# Remove specific file from the input file list of array in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, file

I'm doing a multiple image upload with PHP. When doing the preview, I have provided the button to remove the image as well.

My code is as follow :

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom10">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file_name[]" id="file_name" onchange="preview_image()" class="inputfile" multiple />
    <?php echo '<div class="margin-bottom10">'.form_error('file_name').'</div>'; ?>
    <label class="btn btn-danger" for="file_name"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> &nbsp; Choose image to upload</label>
    &nbsp; <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom10">
    <div class="row" id="image_preview">

    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var newFileList = null;

function preview_image(){
    var total_file=document.getElementById("file_name").files.length;
    newFileList = Array.from(event.target.files);
    for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++){
        $('#image_preview').append("<div class='col-md-2 margin-top10 appendedImg'><img style='width: 100%; height: 130px; object-fit: cover;' src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><button class='btn btn-block btn-danger margin-top5 btnRemove' value='"+i+"'>Remove</button></div>");
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.btnRemove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.appendedImg').remove();
    var id = $(this).val();
    newFileList.splice(id,1);
});
```

As what you can see from my code, I've successfully done with the removing a specific file from the list by saving to an array first then only use the `splice()` to delete.

So, my question is, is it possible to assign the php `$_FILES` array value with the  `newFileList` array value? Since, the deletion only working on the javascript side so it doesn't affect the list from the file input of php array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file list of the input is read only which is how the `$_FILES` global is set.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

However, you could set a hidden element that stores the files that "have been removed" and filter them in PHP on post.

Consider the following example:

When the remove button is used it adds the file name to an array which is covered to a JSON string in a hidden element.

On post, loop through the `$_FILES` global and if the file name is in the remove list then don't process it.

Of course you'll want to make the uploads less loose and more secure but I hope this gives you the idea.

(I haven't tested this so you may have to adjust.)

## HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom10">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file_name[]" id="file_name" class="inputfile" multiple />
    <label class="btn btn-danger" for="file_name"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> &nbsp; Choose image to upload</label>
    &nbsp; <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom10">
    <div class="row" id="image_preview">

    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="removed_files" name="removed_files" value="" />
```

## JavaScript

```
window.newFileList = [];

$(document).on('click', '.btnRemove', function () {
  var remove_element = $(this);
  var id = remove_element.val();
  remove_element.closest('.appendedImg').remove();
  var input = document.getElementById('file_name');
  var files = input.files;
  if (files.length) {
     if (typeof files[id] !== 'undefined') {
       window.newFileList.push(files[id].name)
     }
  }
  document.getElementById('removed_files').value = JSON.stringify(window.newFileList);
});

$(document).on('change', '#file_name', function (event) {
    var total_file = document.getElementById("file_name").files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < total_file; i++) {
        $('#image_preview').append("<div class='col-md-2 margin-top10 appendedImg'><img style='width: 100%; height: 130px; object-fit: cover;' src='" + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + "'><button class='btn btn-block btn-danger margin-top5 btnRemove' value='" + i + "'>Remove</button></div>");
    }
});
```

## PHP

```
<?php
$removedImages = json_decode($_POST['removed_files'], true);
foreach ($_FILES['file_name'] as $FILE) {
    if (in_array($FILE['name'], $removedImages)) {
        continue;
    }

    // [import file stuff]
}
```

Comment: Greate idea! Thank you :)